# Add cart jquery preventDefault not working for multi product in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Here I am trying to make a cart selection for multiple product

```
<?php foreach ($diagnosis as $diagnosi): ?>
    <td class="actions">
            <?php echo $this->Form->create('Cart',array('id'=>'add-form','url'=>array('controller'=>'carts','action'=>'add')));?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('product_id',array('value'=>$diagnosi['Diagnosi']['id']))?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Add',array('class'=>'btn-success btn btn-lg'));?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end();
            ?>
            </td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this is my jquery code

```
$('#add-form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var tis = $(this);
                $.post("<?php echo  Router::url(array('controller'=>'carts','action'=>'add'));?>",tis.serialize(),function(data){
                    $('#cart-counter').text(data);
                });
                alert(tis.serialize());
            });
```

Here problem is it's working for first product after search product, but when I am going to click on 2nd product preventDefault(); is not working.
Here is the output like 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that id must be unique in HTML document, however your are creating multiple form elements with the same ids. Try to use class names instead:

```
<?php foreach ($diagnosis as $diagnosi): ?>
<td class="actions">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Cart',array('class'=>'add-form','url'=>array('controller'=>'carts','action'=>'add')));?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('product_id',array('value'=>$diagnosi['Diagnosi']['id']))?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Add',array('class'=>'btn-success btn btn-lg'));?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And JS code will use class selector to bind submit events to each form:

```
$('.add-form').submit(function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: ohh !! A full days I have wasted on this issue.Thanks a lot.